# Populate javascript template at startup global.asax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, startup

I use asp.net mvc & going to build javascript files at application startup depending on site configuration.

I am going to have some javascript file templates that will be populated with appropriate constants and put into /scripts folder.

Please, suggest me the best way to do that. I want to have something like:

application_startup() 
{
  string populatedFile = Html.RenderPartial("/scripts/script.template.js");
  write populatedFile into /scripts folder... 
}

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at putting the logic in ASHX handler rather than Global.asax, then reference the ASHX as a script reference in your Site Master.

With regards to the actual logic. I'd be pulling your templates using a reader and creating the final script with a String Builder.

If the configuration is not going to change that much, make sure you are caching your output.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you very much! What a good idea! :)
I created controller that renders populated javascript files via partial views with OutputCache attribute applied to methods